# Pass the information from Input Button to the Labels

Tags: java

I am trying to make the showBtn or Input button to pass the information that the User will input in the TextFields(itemNameTF, itemNumTF, itemUPCTF, itemQtyTF, and itemUMTF) to show up in the two labels(itemQtyLbl, itemUMLbl), but all I am getting is an error and when I push the Input button I am getting the next window, but in the next window when I push the "show" button I don`t get the info that the User input in the TextFields, I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.TextField;

public class EnterItemInfo extends UsefulFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Label compNameLbl = null;
    private Button showBtn = null;
    private Label itemQtyLbl = null;
    private Label itemUMLbl = null;
    public Item item;
    private Label itemNameLbl = null;
    private Label itemNumLbl = null;
    private Label itemUPCLbl = null;
    private TextField itemNameTF = null;
    private TextField itemNumTF = null;
    private TextField itemUPCTF = null;
    private TextField itemQtyTF = null;
    private TextField itemUMTF = null;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // itemQtyLbl.setText(item.getItemQty() + " " + item.getItemUM() + " " +
        // item.getItemName() + " " + "units");
        // itemUMLbl.setText("were received with a UPC of" + " " +
        // item.getItemUPC());

        itemQtyLbl.setText(getItemQtyTF() + " " + getItemUMTF() + " "
                + getItemNameTF() + " " + "units");
        itemUMLbl.setText("were received with a UPC of" + " " + getItemUPCTF());

        itemNameTF.setText("");
        itemNumTF.setText("");
        itemUPCTF.setText("");
        itemQtyTF.setText("");
        itemUMTF.setText("");
        ItemFrame iFrame = new ItemFrame(item);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * This is the default constructor
     * 
     * @param i
     */
    public EnterItemInfo() {
        super();

        initialize();

    }

    /**
     * This method initializes this
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    private void initialize() {
        itemUPCLbl = new Label();
        itemUPCLbl.setForeground(Color.green);
        itemUPCLbl.setLocation(new Point(74, 185));
        itemUPCLbl.setSize(new Dimension(120, 23));
        itemUPCLbl.setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
        itemUPCLbl.setText("UPC Code");
        itemNumLbl = new Label();
        itemNumLbl.setForeground(Color.green);
        itemNumLbl.setLocation(new Point(74, 132));
        itemNumLbl.setSize(new Dimension(120, 23));
        itemNumLbl.setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
        itemNumLbl.setText("Item Number");
        itemNameLbl = new Label();
        itemNameLbl.setForeground(Color.green);
        itemNameLbl.setLocation(new Point(74, 79));
        itemNameLbl.setSize(new Dimension(120, 23));
        itemNameLbl.setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
        itemNameLbl.setText("Item Name");
        itemUMLbl = new Label();
        itemUMLbl.setText("Unit of Measure");
        itemUMLbl.setSize(new Dimension(120, 20));
        itemUMLbl.setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
        itemUMLbl.setForeground(Color.green);
        itemUMLbl.setLocation(new Point(74, 288));
        itemQtyLbl = new Label();
        itemQtyLbl.setText("Quantity");
        itemQtyLbl.setSize(new Dimension(120, 20));
        itemQtyLbl.setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
        itemQtyLbl.setForeground(Color.green);
        itemQtyLbl.setLocation(new Point(74, 238));
        compNameLbl = new Label();
        compNameLbl.setText("TNT Salvage");
        compNameLbl.setSize(new Dimension(384, 36));
        compNameLbl.setBackground(Color.orange);
        compNameLbl.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        compNameLbl.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
        compNameLbl.setLocation(new Point(8, 30));
        this.setSize(400, 350);
        this.setTitle("Item Information");
        Item item = new Item("", "", "", "", "");

        this.add(compNameLbl, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.add(itemQtyLbl, null);
        this.add(itemUMLbl, null);
        this.add(itemNameLbl, null);
        this.add(itemNumLbl, null);
        this.add(itemUPCLbl, null);
        this.add(getItemNameTF(), null);
        this.add(getItemNumTF(), null);
        this.add(getItemUPCTF(), null);
        this.add(getItemQtyTF(), null);
        this.add(getItemUMTF(), null);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.add(getShowBtn(), null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setExitButtonLocation();

    }

    /**
     * This method initializes showBtn
     * 
     * @return java.awt.Button
     */
    private Button getShowBtn() {
        if (showBtn == null) {
            showBtn = new Button();
            showBtn.setLocation(new Point(164, 323));
            showBtn.setLabel("Input");
            showBtn.setName("inputBTN");
            showBtn.setSize(new Dimension(60, 20));
            showBtn.addActionListener(this);
        }
        return showBtn;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes itemNameTF
     * 
     * @return java.awt.TextField
     */
    private TextField getItemNameTF() {
        if (itemNameTF == null) {
            itemNameTF = new TextField();
            itemNameTF.setLocation(new Point(204, 79));
            itemNameTF.setSize(new Dimension(150, 23));
        }
        return itemNameTF;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes itemNumTF
     * 
     * @return java.awt.TextField
     */
    private TextField getItemNumTF() {
        if (itemNumTF == null) {
            itemNumTF = new TextField();
            itemNumTF.setLocation(new Point(204, 132));
            itemNumTF.setSize(new Dimension(50, 23));
        }
        return itemNumTF;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes itemUPCTF
     * 
     * @return java.awt.TextField
     */
    private TextField getItemUPCTF() {
        if (itemUPCTF == null) {
            itemUPCTF = new TextField();
            itemUPCTF.setLocation(new Point(204, 185));
            itemUPCTF.setSize(new Dimension(75, 23));
        }
        return itemUPCTF;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes itemQtyTF
     * 
     * @return java.awt.TextField
     */
    private TextField getItemQtyTF() {
        if (itemQtyTF == null) {
            itemQtyTF = new TextField();
            itemQtyTF.setLocation(new Point(204, 238));
            itemQtyTF.setSize(new Dimension(50, 23));
        }
        return itemQtyTF;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes itemUMTF
     * 
     * @return java.awt.TextField
     */
    private TextField getItemUMTF() {
        if (itemUMTF == null) {
            itemUMTF = new TextField();
            itemUMTF.setLocation(new Point(204, 288));
            itemUMTF.setSize(new Dimension(75, 23));
        }
        return itemUMTF;
    }

} // @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="10,8"
```

Comment: And the problem you're getting is?

Comment: You've shown over 200 lines of code - way more than you need to demonstrate the problem - but you haven't actually asked a question. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Please only post the relevant code instead of relying on us to fish through everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your actionPerformed, just get all the text `someTextField.getText()`, then set the text in the Label `someLabel.setText("someText");`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    // example
    String someTextFieldInput = someTextField.getText();

    // if they are numbers from the field, you must parse
    // example
    int someInt = Integer.parseInt(someTextField.getText();

    // after you get all your input from the text fields, add them to labels
    someLabel.setText(someTextFieldInput);
    someOtherLabel.setText(String.valueOf(someInt));

}
```

You should also have you `ItemFrame` as an inner class of `EnterItemInfo`, that way it can use all it textfields. Have the actionperformed where you're getting the text inside the `EnterItemInfo` and register it to the button in that class.

```
public class EnterItemInfo extends JFrame {
    private ItemFrame iFrame = new iFrame();
    ... all text fields and labels

    private JButton showBut = new JButton("show");

    public ItemFrame(){
        ... add components
        iFrame.setVisible(false);
        add(iFrame);

        add(showBut);
        showBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            iFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private class ItemFrame extends JFrame {
        private JButton button = new JButton("show info");
        public ItemFrame(){
            add(new JLabel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(button, borderLayout.NORTH);

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                ... do stuff
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Or you can just have ItemFrame extends EnterItemFrame. I'm not sure if you're having a problem getting input from one frame to the next. If not, just keep it the way you had.